# Make a [conversion] to proper tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags, tag-cleanup-request

I couldn't think of a pun for the title that wouldn't sound more forced than witty, so the current title comes courtesy of Canadian Luke.

Looking at the [conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conversion) tag, the vast majority of the questions using it seem to actually be about [file-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-conversion). [conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conversion)'s description explicitly recommends selecting a more specific tag if possible. For this purpose, I recently added a [filesystem-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-conversion) question for a few of my own questions.

In the context of SU, I can't really think of any other types of conversion apart from file and filesystem, so I'm wondering whether it would make more sense for [conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conversion) to be deprecated, and for all the questions that use it to be tagged with [file-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-conversion) and [filesystem-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-conversion) as appropriate. There are only around 1000 questions currently tagged as [conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conversion), so I'd be happy to spend as much time as I can offer to help retag these.

What does everyone else think?

Comment: How bout "Make a [conversion] to proper tags"?

Comment: [file-conversion] seems too broad to me.  Documents, images, and media files are likely to be answered by users with different expertise, and the questions will be of interest to different users.  I'd suggest separate tags for major categories of file conversion.  There's also another category not mentioned--signal conversion (e.g., how do I convert my VGA output to HDMI?).  Not sure the users asking the questions would think of signal conversion as a tag, but typing "conversion" would pop up the various conversion tags.

Comment: Good point about splitting files up into respective types. Signal conversion didn't occur to me, but then I didn't see any signal conversion questions when looking through [conversion]. Either way, I agree that the more specificity the better. I just primarily feel like conversion needs to be gotten rid of.

Comment: @fixer1234 We already have [audio-conversion], [video-conversion] and [image-conversion] as well as [file-conversion]

Comment: Perhaps [document-conversion], covering questions about conversion between word/openoffice/libreoffice, and between txt/csv would also be useful

Comment: We have around 1000 questions tagged [conversion], and 5500 containing the word "conversion" - too many to quickly fix, so this would be a candidate for the next tag cleanup weekend.

Comment: @DavidPostill Good shout on the filetype conversion tags, I didn't notice those. When is the next tag cleanup weekend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### We should break the tag into more specific subcategories

I agree with your proposal. The [conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conversion) tag somewhat broad and borders on being too meta. Breaking the tag into more focused areas would resolve this nicely.

Comment: Note to self: Add more detail when not on mobile.